# How to change the binary of diff in shell?

Tags: python, shell

I was using shell test script to test my python file in Grieg, and the following error message shown.
[image]
It seems like that I have the wrong binary of diff, I would like to know how could I change my diff from 
*/import/path/bin/diff* to */usr/bin/diff*

Comment: Please provide the code that throws this error

Comment: Do you know why there is (non-empty) `/etc/ld.so.preload` on your system?

Comment: @vkozyrev this is my assignment I'm very sorry that I don't think that I'm allowed to post my code